# Compile a MYSQL example with Clang

Tags: mysql, c, clang

EHLO

I am trying to compile an example of mysql connecion on C with Clang, while I can do it with gcc easily like this:

```
gcc mysql1.c -o mysql1 -std=c99  `mysql_config --cflags --libs`
```

I don't know how to pass the script mysql_config parameter to clang. I did it without them, but clang gave me errors about the include on library mysql.h and others.

what can I do?

Comment: What does `mysql_config --cflags --libs` display?

Comment: This: -I/usr/include/mysql -Wa,--compress-debug-sections -gdwarf-4 -fvar-tracking-assignments -frecord-gcc-switches -Wstrict-aliasing=2 -pipe -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -fstack-protector-all -fPIC  -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv  -fPIC -g -DNDEBUG                       
-rdynamic -L/usr/lib64 -lmysqlclient -lpthread -lz -lm -lssl -lcrypto -ldl

Comment: Anybody have a clue?. I haven't found too much online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is how I figured out:

`clang mysql1.c -o mysql1 -I/usr/include/mysql -Wa, -gdwarf-4 -fvar-tracking-assignments -frecord-gcc-switches -Wstrict-aliasing=2 -pipe -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -fstack-protector-all -fPIC -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -fPIC -g -DNDEBUG -rdynamic -L/usr/local/lib/mysql -lmysqlclient -lpthread -lz -lm -lssl -lcrypto -O2`

Just have in mind where are mysqlclient lib and mysql sources.